# Cannot get port to close

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcp

I am trying to fix an app that uses TCP to receive files. Unfortunately, I do not have the source code for the sending application. The problem that I am having is that after the first file is received, the second one is sent by the sending application, but it is not being picked up by the receiving application.

I believe the issue is that the socket is not being closed after receiving the file. I have a method that should close it, but _socket.Connected = false, so nothing is done. However, if I check the port, it is still bound, even after the socket is closed.

```
    Private Sub CloseSocket(ByVal disconnect As Boolean)
        If Not (_socket Is Nothing) Then
            If (_socket.Connected = True) Then
                _socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both)
                If(disconnect) Then
                    _socket.Disconnect(True)
                End If
            End If
            _socket.Close()
            _socket = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub
```

I realize that I have not included much code, but the Listen method is quite large and convoluted. I can get additional code if it will provide insight. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

EDITED

The code that is used to check the port status is below:

```
    Private Shared Function TcpIpGetPortStatus(ByVal port As Int32) As String

        Dim properties As NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties
        Dim listeners As Net.IPEndPoint()
        Dim local As Net.IPEndPoint
        Dim connections As NetworkInformation.TcpConnectionInformation()
        Dim t As NetworkInformation.TcpConnectionInformation
        Dim portStatus As String

        portStatus = "Disconnected"
        properties = NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties()
        listeners = properties.GetActiveTcpListeners()

        Try
            ' Cycle through all listening TCP connections and find the one that is associated with port.
            For Each local In listeners
                If (local.Port = port) Then
                    portStatus = "Connected"
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next local

            ' Port wasn't in the listening state so check if it is established.
            If (portStatus = "Disconnected") Then
                properties = NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties()
                connections = properties.GetActiveTcpConnections()

                ' Cycle through all active TCP connections and find the one that is associated with port.
                For Each t In connections
                    If (t.LocalEndPoint.Port = port) Then
                        Select Case t.State
                            Case NetworkInformation.TcpState.Established
                                portStatus = "Connected"
                                Exit For
                        End Select
                    End If
                Next t
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' Handle Exception...
        End Try

        Return portStatus

    End Function
```

This function will return "Connected" when called. I've traced it through, and found that the port I was using was still bound. Again, thank you for all help.

ADDITION

I just ran this between two separate systems, using WireShark to capture the data. There is a Sender and Receiver that I do not have sourcecode for, and am trying to integrate with, and the Sender and Receiver that I am updating the code to get it to communicate properly with the existing ones. The stream sent is identical in both cases (except for datetime in the ACK). If I send a second message from the existing sender to the Receiver being upgraded, the message is sent to the port, but the Receiver in development is never notified, which hangs both programs.

Comment: Maybe the issue is that the socket *is* closed after receiving the file and you are supposed to leave it open for another file on the same connection?

Comment: Why not simply remove the check for `Connected`and just call `ShutDown()` and `Disconnect()` unconditionally?

Comment: @Remy I did try that, but a Socket Exception was thrown. It says the socket is not connected, but when I check the list of open sockets, I find that it is connected. I have added the code that is used to check for open connections.

Comment: Actually, he just needs to call _socket.Close() and _socket.Dispose() unconditionally. (Put it in a try/catch block to catch any exceptions). Skip the Disconnect and Shutdown call. That's likely the best way to close the socket. But I suspect EJP's suggestion is correct.  The socket shouldn't be closed at all.

Comment: @selbie Thank you for your response. I do call _socket.Close, which seems like it should release the socket, but it remains open. However, I am looking into the possibility that I should be leaving the connection open. I have removed all calls to CloseSocket, but am still running into the issue of the next file not being received. I suppose I should start researching whether something needs to be done to start the application listening again after receiving the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After pouring over the code that was provided to me, I finally realized that it was closing and disconnecting the wrong socket. Rather than calling Shutdown and Disconnect on the socket that was used to receive the message, it was called on the listening socket.

Once i realized this, I was able to close the correct socket, and the application began to work. Now I just need to go through and correct all of the issues that this caused with the underlying code, and things should be good.

Thank you to all of the people who responded. You got me thinking in the right direction.